# Código fica todo branco no VS Code, sem realce de sintaxe nem sugestões

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quando eu coloco a extensão ".htm" no arquivo, volta a funcionar com as cores normais e sugestões, porém todas as minhas aplicações estão configuradas com ".html". Já desinstalei e instalei não resolveu. Alguém sabe o motivo?

[image: imagem do cod. em branco]

[image: minhas extensões]

Comment: Põe como Detecção Automática. (Busca no rodapé do vscode à direita)

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de passar por isso.
Então o que fiz foi ir em *Manage*, *Settings*, *User* e em *Files Associations*, eu tinha uma associação de arquivos *.html com njk. Apaguei-a, voltei no meu código e tudo havia voltado ao normal. Se esta associação é útil para você, talvez pudesse encontrar uma outra forma de configurá-la.
Espero que tenha te ajudado!

Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Para mudar essa configuração basta modificar como o arquivo é reconhecido pelo VScode.

Para fazer essa mudança:

1. Clique em: `select language mode`
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Na caixa de texto que abrir digite: `html`
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Aperte enter
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. O texto deve estar em envidência corretamente.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]