# Código javascript fica todo branco no Visual studio, sem realce de sintaxe

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Encontrei uma situação semelhante mas referente ao "Visual Studio Code" conforme segue nesse link:
[Código fica todo branco no VS Code, sem realce de sintaxe nem sugestões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456784/c%C3%B3digo-fica-todo-branco-no-vs-code-sem-realce-de-sintaxe-nem-sugest%C3%B5es)

mas o meu problema ocorre no "Visual Studio", recentemente foi feita uma atualização obrigatória. E os arquivos que contém códigos javascript no meio, como por exemplo arquivos .cshtml (que contém trechos inclusive de html e javascript pelas tags ) ficaram com o código javascript todo branco, sem a coloração da sintaxe.
já tentei ir em ferramentas>opções>Editor de texto e vincular a extensão cshtml com alguns editores mas nenhum surtiu efeito desejável.
Alguém já passou por isso e sabe como corrigi-la?

Answer (score -1):

No rodapé do programa tem uma barra que mostra informações do documento, clica em Plain Text e seleciona a linguagem que você está trabalhando, no caso HTML[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]